# Error while starting Kafka on Windows 10 using kafka-server-start.bat on windows. Giving AccessDenied excpetion

Tags: apache-kafka

Earlier, I tried running kafka **2.13-3.0.0** on windows 10 with Java 8. After making changes to the config\zookeeper.properties and zonfig\server.properties file, adding a path in logs.dir variable, my zookeeper start running, but I am unable to get the kafka serve up, it is always giving the issue mentioned below:

> Error while writing to checkpoint file D:\kafka_2.13-3.0.0\data\kafka\recovery-point-offset-checkpoint (kafka.server.LogDirFailureChannel)
> java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: D:\kafka_2.13-3.0.0\data\kafka** at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:89) at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:103) at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:108) at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newFileChannel(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:120) at java.base/java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(FileChannel.java:292) at java.base/java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(FileChannel.java:345)
> at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.flushDir(Utils.java:953) at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.atomicMoveWithFallback(Utils.java:941) at kafka.server.checkpoints.CheckpointFile.liftedTree1$1(CheckpointFile.scala:114) at kafka.server.checkpoints.CheckpointFile.write(CheckpointFile.scala:92) at kafka.server.checkpoints.OffsetCheckpointFile.write(OffsetCheckpointFile.scala:67) at kafka.log.LogManager.$anonfun$checkpointRecoveryOffsetsInDir$1(LogManager.scala:675) at kafka.log.LogManager.$anonfun$checkpointRecoveryOffsetsInDir$1$adapted(LogManager.scala:671) at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:437) at kafka.log.LogManager.checkpointRecoveryOffsetsInDir(LogManager.scala:671) at kafka.log.LogManager.$anonfun$shutdown$9(LogManager.scala:542) at kafka.log.LogManager.$anonfun$shutdown$9$adapted(LogManager.scala:535) at kafka.utils.Implicits$MapExtensionMethods$.$anonfun$forKeyValue$1(Implicits.scala:62) at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$Node.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:633) at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:499) at kafka.log.LogManager.shutdown(LogManager.scala:535) at kafka.server.KafkaServer.$anonfun$shutdown$18(KafkaServer.scala:701)
> at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.swallow(CoreUtils.scala:68)
> at kafka.server.KafkaServer.shutdown(KafkaServer.scala:701)
> at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:435)
> at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:109)
> at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
> [2021-10-25 23:37:06,621] ERROR Disk error while writing recovery offsets checkpoint in directory D:\kafka_2.13-3.0.0\data\kafka: Error while writing to checkpoint file D:\kafka_2.13-3.0.0\data\kafka\recovery-point-offset-checkpoint (kafka.log.LogManager)
> [2021-10-25 23:37:06,626] ERROR Error while writing to checkpoint file D:\kafka_2.13-3.0.0\data\kafka\log-start-offset-checkpoint (kafka.server.LogDirFailureChannel)
> java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: D:\kafka_2.13-3.0.0\data\kafka
> at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:89)
> at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:103)
> at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:108)
> at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newFileChannel(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:120)
> at java.base/java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(FileChannel.java:292)
> at java.base/java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(FileChannel.java:345)
> at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.flushDir(Utils.java:953)
> at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.atomicMoveWithFallback(Utils.java:941)
> at kafka.server.checkpoints.CheckpointFile.liftedTree1$1(CheckpointFile.scala:114)
> at kafka.server.checkpoints.CheckpointFile.write(CheckpointFile.scala:92)
> at kafka.server.checkpoints.OffsetCheckpointFile.write(OffsetCheckpointFile.scala:67)
> at kafka.log.LogManager.$anonfun$checkpointLogStartOffsetsInDir$1(LogManager.scala:698)
> at kafka.log.LogManager.$anonfun$checkpointLogStartOffsetsInDir$1$adapted(LogManager.scala:694)
> at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:437)
> at kafka.log.LogManager.checkpointLogStartOffsetsInDir(LogManager.scala:694)
> at kafka.log.LogManager.$anonfun$shutdown$9(LogManager.scala:545)
> at kafka.log.LogManager.$anonfun$shutdown$9$adapted(LogManager.scala:535)
> at kafka.utils.Implicits$MapExtensionMethods$.$anonfun$forKeyValue$1(Implicits.scala:62)
> at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$Node.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:633)
> at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:499)
> at kafka.log.LogManager.shutdown(LogManager.scala:535)
> at kafka.server.KafkaServer.$anonfun$shutdown$18(KafkaServer.scala:701)
> at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.swallow(CoreUtils.scala:68)
> at kafka.server.KafkaServer.shutdown(KafkaServer.scala:701)
> at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:435)
> at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:109)
> at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)

After looking at solutions on the net, I found this issue is majorly visible in the latest kafka versions, so I installed **2.12-2.0.0** as well (the version which the guy in the tutorial from where I was learning from, used) and tried the same thing again, it is again giving the same error mentioned above. Is it impossible to run kafka on windows 10? If yes, then what are the alternatives? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: For the latest versions of Kafka, installation in WSL2 is recommended. Give this a try [Confluent](https://www.confluent.io/blog/set-up-and-run-kafka-on-windows-linux-wsl-2/#enable-windows-subsystem)

Comment: Hi, thankyou for the recommendation, I am just curious in this section as i tried it with kafka as old as 4 years old as well, with the version 2.10-0.10.0.1 (2016 version) and still getting the same error. And I am unable to understand why does kafka doesn't give same error in everyone's machine who is running it on windows (I have seen blogs and videos where devs are running it on windows with versions of 2018)

Comment: It might **start** for them (sometimes). But it will not **run** completely over time